# Parsing XML in iOS?

Tags: ios, xml, parsing

I need to parse simple XML coming from my webserver and store this in database. 
How do I do the same?

Answer (score 9):

Please have a look at [Touch XML](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchXML), a Objective-C framework for reading and writing XML. It's usage is similar (drop-in replacement) for Apple's NSXMLDocument (which is not available for the iPhone SDK).

Comment: -1 for the link does not seem to work currently, sorry.

Comment: @DerMike I have updated the link. Can I have my +1 back ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Apple has two built in solutions for parsing XML data on the iphone:

1) Apple has an objective-c implementation of an XML parser called NSXMLParser.  [See documentation here.](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

2) Apple also has a C based implementation of an XML parser called libXML2.  [See documentation here. - scroll down to see section on XML support](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/iPhoneOSTechnologies/iPhoneOSTechnologies.html)

Answer (score 4):

At the end of the article you can find a full project example.

http://www.hivestudio.cat/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=60:xml-parser-for-iphone&catid=35:technical-note-category&Itemid=76

Answer (score 3):

you can check here ,might be it will help you.
http://homepages.ius.edu/rwisman/C490/html/nsxmlparser.html

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://www.tbxml.co.uk for a super-fast, lightweight, easy to use XML parser!

Answer (score 1):

The above mentioned *Touch XML*, seems to be discountinued. [KissXML](http://code.google.com/p/kissxml/) is an alternative. It is based on *Touch XML*, but has more features.

[GDataXML](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/XMLSupport/) could also be an alternative, its developed by Google.