# How to get data from xml file on iOS

Tags: ios

What I did on iOS is displaying grid of 10 images. For this I take a array and add all images to array. For this I am write the code as:

```
[_image addImage:[UIImage ImageNamed:@"black.jpg"]];
```

like this I add all images to array. Now what I need is to get all the images through Xml file and add to the images array. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The class you need is `NSXMLParser` and the delegate `NSXMLParserDelegate`.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](http://craiggiles.wordpress.com/2009/01/14/parsing-xml-on-the-iphone/) or [even here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021102/parsing-xml-in-iphone-xcode). What you are looking for is to parse an XML document, and you can do it with the [`NSXMLParser`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class, [libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/), or other libs/tools mainly based on those two. Also you'd better have a look [at this project by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/XMLPerformance/Introduction/Intro.html) it will show you the main differences in terms of performance between technologies

Comment: Thanks for the link to the Apple project, didn't know about it!

Comment: @Stelian Iancu it is probably the best first place to start when you have doubts on whether using libxml2 or NSXMLParser (plus it show pretty clearly how to use both)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to parse your xml file. You can use the [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsxmlparser) class. How exactly you would do this, depends on the structure of your xml file. There are a lot of tutorials on the Internet about how to use it, for example see [here](http://theappleblog.com/2008/08/04/tutorial-build-a-simple-rss-reader-for-iphone/).