# XML parser SDK for IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, parsing, sdk

I need to be able to parse XML for a project I'm working on.

How can I parse XML from a web page to the iPhone then read its contents?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705588/nsxmlparser-example

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing XML in iphone Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021102/parsing-xml-in-iphone-xcode)

Comment: Please, sir, step away from XCode. Quickly put your hands on an iOS programming book. Any duplicate question that shows complete lack of former research can and will be used against your rep. You have the right to read documentation. If you cannot find documentation, it will be presented to you by Google. Do you understand these rights?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry, I learn by working with the program not by reading a book. I actually have very little patience with books. I did research for this question and i found nothing helpful. I am sorry if i offended anyone for asking this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this , [how to parse XML in Objective c](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) using ASIHTTPRequest and handle all this methods

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
```

See this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) too

Answer (score 0):

```
          NSString *url=@"http://www.lancers.jp/work";

            NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
            NSDictionary *dict=[XMLParser dictionaryForXMLData:data error:nil];

            NSLog(@"%@",[dict description]);


    and use below file::::::


    XMLParser.h

   //
//  XMLReader.h
//
//  Created by Troy on 9/18/10.
//  Copyright 2010 Troy Brant. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface XMLParser : NSObject<NSXMLParserDelegate>
{
    NSMutableArray *dictionaryStack;
    NSMutableString *textInProgress;
    NSError **errorPointer;
}

+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryForXMLData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError **)errorPointer;
+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryForXMLString:(NSString *)string error:(NSError **)errorPointer;

@end


XMLParser.m

//
//  XMLReader.m
//
//  Created by Troy on 9/18/10.
//  Copyright 2010 Troy Brant. All rights reserved.
//

#import "XMLParser.h"

NSString *const kXMLReaderTextNodeKey = @"text";

@interface XMLParser (Internal)

- (id)initWithError:(NSError **)error;
- (NSDictionary *)objectWithData:(NSData *)data;

@end


//NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",NSLocalizedString(@"locationname", nil)];
//url=[NSString stringWithFormat:url,app.latnear,app.lngnear];
//NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
//NSDictionary *dict=[XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:data error:nil];


@implementation XMLParser

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Public methods

+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryForXMLData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError **)error
{
    XMLParser *reader = [[XMLParser alloc] initWithError:error];
    NSDictionary *rootDictionary = [reader objectWithData:data];
    [reader release];
    return rootDictionary;
}

+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryForXMLString:(NSString *)string error:(NSError **)error
{
    NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    return [XMLParser dictionaryForXMLData:data error:error];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Parsing

- (id)initWithError:(NSError **)error
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        errorPointer = error;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [dictionaryStack release];
    [textInProgress release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (NSDictionary *)objectWithData:(NSData *)data
{
    // Clear out any old data
    [dictionaryStack release];
    [textInProgress release];

    dictionaryStack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    textInProgress = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    // Initialize the stack with a fresh dictionary
    [dictionaryStack addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]];

    // Parse the XML
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    parser.delegate = self;
    BOOL success = [parser parse];

    // Return the stack's root dictionary on success
    if (success)
    {
        NSDictionary *resultDict = [dictionaryStack objectAtIndex:0];
        return resultDict;
    }

    return nil;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark NSXMLParserDelegate methods

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    // Get the dictionary for the current level in the stack
    NSMutableDictionary *parentDict = [dictionaryStack lastObject];

    // Create the child dictionary for the new element, and initilaize it with the attributes
    NSMutableDictionary *childDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [childDict addEntriesFromDictionary:attributeDict];

    // If there's already an item for this key, it means we need to create an array
    id existingValue = [parentDict objectForKey:elementName];
    if (existingValue)
    {
        NSMutableArray *array = nil;
        if ([existingValue isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]])
        {
            // The array exists, so use it
            array = (NSMutableArray *) existingValue;
        }
        else
        {
            // Create an array if it doesn't exist
            array = [NSMutableArray array];
            [array addObject:existingValue];

            // Replace the child dictionary with an array of children dictionaries
            [parentDict setObject:array forKey:elementName];
        }

        // Add the new child dictionary to the array
        [array addObject:childDict];
    }
    else
    {
        // No existing value, so update the dictionary
        [parentDict setObject:childDict forKey:elementName];
    }

    // Update the stack
    [dictionaryStack addObject:childDict];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    // Update the parent dict with text info
    NSMutableDictionary *dictInProgress = [dictionaryStack lastObject];

    // Set the text property
    if ([textInProgress length] > 0)
    {
        [dictInProgress setObject:textInProgress forKey:kXMLReaderTextNodeKey];

        // Reset the text
        [textInProgress release];
        textInProgress = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }

    // Pop the current dict
    [dictionaryStack removeLastObject];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    // Build the text value
    [textInProgress appendString:string];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError
{
    // Set the error pointer to the parser's error object
    *errorPointer = parseError;
}

@end
```