# iOS google maps directions API used in code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, google-maps, directions

I'm trying to fetch the XML result from an exmaple query like this:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Toronto,ON&destination=Manhattan,NY&dirflg=r&sensor=false

in my program. Is there a way to fetch the XML results in Objective-C code? I don't want my application to open Maps application. I want to be able to receive the XML. I do have a MapKit in my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.  Just do something like this:

```
NSXMLParser * xmlParser = 
    [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Toronto,ON&destination=Manhattan,NY&dirflg=r&sensor=false"];
```

The [Apple documentation for NSXMLParser is here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

This may be a bit too heavy duty for your purposes, so you can also do something like the [answers provided for in this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021102/parsing-xml-in-iphone-xcode).

Comment: Ah, great. Do you happen to know why the 'dirflg=r' parameter (switch to public transit) doesn't work?

Comment: not off the top of my head, but post a different question and either I or someone else could come up with a quick answer for you.