# How to parse this xml and retrieve the data in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I am developing an iPad app. We get the data as XML. I am using `NSXMLParser` for parsing, all the data is printed to the console. How to retrieve the values separately?

Another question is how to check the memory leak in iPhone?

```
 <Result>

 <Movieoftheweek>
         <Movie_id>3809</Movie_id>
         <Movieoftheweek_img_Url>"http://www.add.com/adogs/11055.jpg</Movieoftheweek_img_Url>
         <Movie_Name>Luck</Movie_Name>
         <gender>Movie</gender>
    </Movieoftheweek>
<Movie_List_in_theater>  
          <movie_in_theater>
             <Movie_id>3809</Movie_id>
             <Movie_img_Url>http://www.add.com/adogs/11055.jpg</Movie_img_Url>
             <Movie_Name>Luck</Movie_Name>
             <gender>Movie</gender>
          </movie_in_theater>

 <movie_in_theater>
             <Movie_id>3809</Movie_id>
             <Movie_img_Url>http://www.add.com/adogs/6055.jpg</Movie_img_Url>
             <Movie_Name>Luck</Movie_Name>
             <gender>Movie</gender>
          </movie_in_theater>

<movie_in_theater>
             <Movie_id>3809</Movie_id>
             <Movie_img_Url>http://www.add.com/adogs/525.jpg</Movie_img_Url>
             <Movie_Name>Luck</Movie_Name>
             <gender>Movie</gender>
          </movie_in_theater>

</Movie_List_in_theater>  

<Movie_List_Coming_Soon>
          <movie_Coming_Soon>
             <Movie_id>3803</Movie_id>
             <Movie_img_Url>http://www.add.com/adogs/5000.jpg</Movie_img_Url>
             <Movie_Name>Kode</Movie_Name>
             <gender>Movie</gender>
          </movie_Coming_Soon>

 <movie_Coming_Soon>
             <Movie_id>3803</Movie_id>
             <Movie_img_Url>http://www.add.com/adogs/5900.jpg</Movie_img_Url>
             <Movie_Name>Kode</Movie_Name>
             <gender>Movie</gender>
          </movie_Coming_Soon>
 <movie_Coming_Soon>
             <Movie_id>3803</Movie_id>
             <Movie_img_Url>http://www.add.com/adogs/5500.jpg</Movie_img_Url>
             <Movie_Name>Kode</Movie_Name>
             <gender>Movie</gender>
          </movie_Coming_Soon>
</Movie_List_Coming_Soon>
</Result>
```

Comment: http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/parsing-an-xml-file/

Comment: IDK how "checking memory leak" comes into the picture. Manage memory properly and you won't have leaks, boom.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021102/parsing-xml-in-iphone-xcode

Comment: Use TBXML for parsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello before posting do some r and D many posts are available just check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323326/xml-parsing-in-ios-tutorial) it may helps you

in your method

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Result"])
    {
        //Initialize the array.
        arrXMLData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Movieoftheweek"])
    {
        currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    } 
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Movie_List_in_theater"])
    {
        currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if(!currentElementValue)
        currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    else
        [currentElementValue appendString:string];
    NSLog(@"Processing Value: %@", currentElementValue);
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Result"])
        return;
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Movieoftheweek"])
    {
        [arrXMLData addObject:currentElementValue];
    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Movie_List_in_theater"])
    {
        [arrXMLData addObject:currentElementValue];
    }
    [currentElementValue release];
   }
```